React-Native | [BABEL]: Cannot find module 'node:path' [SOLVED Magically?]
This is is for the benefit of anyone who got the same error
The exact error I got was on after running my react-native 0.70.3 project.
index.js: [BABEL]: Cannot find module 'node:path'
Require stack:
- proj_path/node_modules/path-scurry/dist/commonjs/index.js
- proj_path/node_modules/babel-plugin-module-resolver/node_modules/glob/dist/cjs/glob.js
- proj_path/node_modules/babel-plugin-module-resolver/node_modules/glob/dist/cjs/index.js
...
- proj_path/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js (While processing: proj_path/node_modules/babel-plugin-module-resolver/lib/index.js)

Here is the environment details: 
Package.json:
...
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^6.7.5",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.6.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "axios": "^1.2.4",
    "i18next": "^22.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "native-base": "^3.4.25",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.2",
    "react-i18next": "^12.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.70.3",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-maps": "1.8.4",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^14.0.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "3.29.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": "eslint --cache --fix --cache-location ./node_modules/.cache/.eslintcache",
    "*.{js,json,css}": "prettier --write"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "reactNativePermissionsIOS": [
    "Camera",
    "PhotoLibrary",
    "PhotoLibraryAddOnly",
    "LocationWhenInUse"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.26.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.2",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "lint-staged": "^13.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },

...

node version: 18.20.1 (did not actually matter) 
OS: macOS (Ventura) \
I had tried everything from 
rm -rf ~/.gradle 
rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf package-lock.json 
npm cache clean --force 
to 
./gradlew clean, and 
npm i --legacy-peer-deps ---reset-cache \
but the error kept on occurring. However for some reason the error persisted. \
The error then magically went away when I performed the following command: 
react-native start --reset-cache
I need to know WHY. How does this work but not npm cache clean, or reset-cache flags on every other command prior??
React-native is considerably broken.
